# check connection javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check connect with javascript, but I have trying a lot of tutorials but any works for me.

For example I've this code but not works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>  
<head>   
  <title>Online status</title>  
  <script>    
    function updateIndicator() 
    {
     document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';    
    }   
   </script>  
</head> 
<body onload="updateIndicator()" ononline="updateIndicator()"     onoffline="updateIndicator()">   <p>The network is: <span
     id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>  
</body>
</html>
```

Some help? thanks.

Comment: you might want to refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.onLine)

Comment: I am not a JavaScript developer, but it is still clear to me that it would help the experts to answer your question if you included what exactly is going wrong. How exactly does it "not work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: It's working for me.  At least it is saying I'm online.  http://jsfiddle.net/6Gj4v/

Comment: the problem was that i have vmware installed and the adapter is active. However if I disable this adapter works fine.!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Seems like it was a setup problem, will leave this anyway as it could be useful in cases where ononline and onoffline are not supported.

I am not sure ononline and onoffline are going to be well supported, but you can just set an interval to check for the status and update it accordingly. This little fiddle works (just stop your network connection and the status will switch to offline)

http://jsfiddle.net/vpG5b/1/

You can adjust the interval as needed but 500 ms should be good enough and not be too demanding and I added check to only update the status if it has changed (less DOM manipulations), that way you can even have offline/online handlers.

```
var handler = {
    online: function() {
        alert('online');
    },
    offline: function() {
        alert('offline');
    }
};

function isOnline() {

    var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline',
        indicator = document.getElementById('indicator'),
        current = indicator.textContent;

    // only update if it has change
    if (current != status) {

        // update DOM
        indicator.textContent = status;

        // trigger handler
        handler[status]();
    };
};

setInterval(isOnline, 500);
isOnline();​
```